# How to cast this date pattern?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a date with this pattern:

```
var value = "2013/11/07 23:08:53 +0000"
```

When I do:

```
var date = (DateTime)value;
```

I get an `InvalidCastException`. How can I cast that date?

Comment: That is a string not a date. You cannot _cast_ it to `DateTime`, you need to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast a `string` to a `DateTime`. Instead use `DateTime.Parse(value)` to parse the value.

You can also use `DateTime.TryParse(string)` to avoid throwing an exception.

```
var value = "2013/11/07 23:08:53 +0000";

DateTime dateTime;

if(DateTime.TryParse(value, out dateTime))
{
    // The string is a valid DateTime

    // This will output '11:08 PM'
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToShortTimeString());
}
else
{
    // The string is not a valid DateTime
}
```